# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

hi all my app is getting this exception

```
  09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       mPay2Park.zwl.com.StartNow$1
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at mPay2Park.zwl.com.StartNow.<init>(StartNow.java:449)
09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
  09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 09-03 12:11:10.677: E/AndroidRuntime(31704):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the code in the activity which get the exception at this lines

```
        OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener() {
     public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {
         wheelScrolled = true;
     } 
     public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {
         wheelScrolled = false;
     }
}; 
private OnWheelChangedListener days_changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
      public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
          if (!wheelScrolled) {
              ChossenTime = duration_optionsList.get(newValue);
            }
      }
};
```

CAN anyone help me on it please ,this app was working perfectly and once got this exception

Comment: maybe you have to write ChossenTime is lower-case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change u'r library file names to "/libs" and check it.

Looks like as if you haven't the jar added to your APK correctly. Check your project setup. This is a problem with your setup, not a bug of the API.

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17…

this will explain you, how to fix the classdefnotfounderror

Comment: library file name is libs and i add all the jar files to the build bath

Comment: really i don't know where is the problem i'm stuck on it :(

Comment: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 this will explain you, how to fix the classdefnotfounderror